# redirecting to return url after login

Tags: .net, computer-science

I'm trying to use a returnUrl but it's returning null everytime and i'm not sure why.. could anyone help?

In my controller..

```
public ActionResult Login(string invite, string username, string password, string returnUrl)
  {
     if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
        if (!returnUrl.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
           var model = new LoginModel();
           model.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
           return View(model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home");
     }

      Some stuff....

if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
               {
                  return Redirect(returnUrl);
               }
               else
               {
                  return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home");
               }
```

In my login filter

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is MVC code, I think you have a casing issue.

```
string returnUrl
```

and

```
?ReturnUrl=
```

Are not the same. MVC will match the ReturnUrl to a parameter named ReturnUrl, not returnUrl.

Other things to check:

```
public ActionResult Login(string invite, string username, string password, string returnUrl)
  { // Set breakpoint here
```

With a break point in the noted spot, look at the Request object (RawUrl and QueryString properties) to see that the incoming URL has the parameter you are expecting and that you didn't get here from a redirect.

Another thing that could be impacting you is a Route attribute or configuration that could be impacting the processing of values.

Comment: I made that change and it still appears to be redirecting to the home dashboard